# Почему не нужна запятая? Разве это не уточнение?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, уточнения

***У меня в комнате() возле входной двери() стоит гитара.***

Почему на месте скобок не стоят запятые, если "возле входной двери" уточняет "У меня в комнате"? Правильно ли я понимаю, что запятая не ставится, если "возле входной двери" рассматривать как дополнение? Заранее очень благодарен!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. В приведенном примере использованы два обстоятельства с пространственным значением. Мы можем их представить как **неоднородные** координаты места, а можем считать, что второе обстоятельство **уточняет** первое.  Интонационная структура данного предложения допускает оба варианта.
2. Как же делается выбор? Я думаю, что **по контексту**.  При обособлении второго обстоятельства к **основному плану речи** относится сообщение о гитаре в комнате, а более точное расположение идет как **дополнительное**. Но если  рассказ будет связан с тем, что гитара стоит именно возле двери, то это  будет тоже основная информация, тогда обособлять второе обстоятельство  не нужно.

**Важность контекста** можно пояснить на таком примере. Давайте представим, что мы рассказываем какой-то забавный случай, где будет присутствовать гитара, которая стоит возле двери. Если фраза находится **в начале рассказа**, то мы используем **уточнение** (пока это только дополнительные сведения). Но если предложение  поместить **в середину сюжета**, когда эта деталь становится  важной, то обособлять обстоятельство уже не нужно.

3. **В правилах Розенталя** тема излагается иначе. Там считается, что в нашей речи мы  с помощью обстоятельств как бы точно изображаем пространство, но я не думаю, что это так. Вряд ли это кому необходимо, да и просто не имеет смысла, так как считать и обработать эту информацию при речевом контакте просто невозможно. А вот представление информации как основной и уточняющей – это более актуальная задача.

Answer (score 0):

Дети расположились на поляне между кустами. (поляна окружена кустами, а на самой поляне их нет)
Дети расположились на поляне, между кустами. (кусты находятся на самой поляне)

Далеко в лесу раздавались удары топора. (удары топора доносятся из далекой точки в лесу)
Далеко, в лесу, раздавались удары топора. (слушатель находится далеко от леса, из которого доносятся удары топора)

У меня в комнате возле входной двери стоит гитара. (гитара находится в комнате, которая расположена рядом с входной дверью)
У меня в комнате, возле входной двери, стоит гитара. (возможно, в комнате есть дверь на балкон, и говорящий уточняет, что гитара возле входной двери)

Comment: > У меня в комнате возле входной двери стоит гитара. (гитара находится в комнате, которая расположена рядом с входной дверью)

— Совсем необязательно. Возле входной двери может находиться гитара, а не комната, и запятая все равно может не ставиться. Смысл будет как в "гитара стоит возле входной двери у меня в комнате".

Comment: Если между «в комнате» и «возле входной двери» нет запятой, то это комната расположенная возле входной двери — оборот места, где слова относятся друг к другу. Если  «возле входной двери» обособляется запятыми, то это уточнение(я называю «ограничение») и это место внутри комнаты.

Comment: Если обособляется запятыми — да, однозначно внутри комнаты. Если не обособляется — возможны варианты, потому что в русском языке порядок слов не фиксирован.

Comment: Дверь в комнату не называют входной. Сочетания слов «возле входной двери, у меня в комнате, ...» требуют запятой, так как это расширение — обратное уточнению. Я лежал на кровати, в незнакомой гостинице, и чувствовал спокойствие.